# Javascript tabs alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a forms with different tabs each tabs contain some required inputs I wanna show an alert with the name of the tab if there is one required input that is not filled.

**Here's my code:**

```
fd.onsubmit(function() {
    if (fd.field('FileLeafRef').value().length == 0) {

        alert('Merci de renseigner le champ Nom du client');

        return false;

    }

    if( (fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Secteur_activite').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('logo2').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Type_Effectifs').value().length == 0)){
        // activating a second tab:

        alert('L’onglet «  Client »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }
    if (fd.field('Code_postal_x002d_batiment').value().length == 0) {
        alert('L’onglet «  Bâtiment »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }
    if((fd.field('Surface').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Origine_affaire').value().length == 0)) {
        // activating a second tab:

        alert('L’onglet «  Projet »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

It work fine when there's an empty input , but show me all the time the first message `alert ('«  Client »  contains empty inputs!!');`.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't put "else", but other "if". It depends if you want to show many alerts when there is more empty tabs. Also, isn't this

```
if(fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value().length == 0)
```

or

```
if(!fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value().length)
```

the correct format?

Also, when you have empty fields, I guess you wanted to return false, didn't you?

So the full function would look like this

```
fd.onsubmit(function() {
    if( (fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Secteur_activite').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('logo2').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Type_Effectifs').value().length == 0)){
        // activating a second tab:

        alert('L’onglet «  Client »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }
    if (fd.field('Code_postal_x002d_batiment').value().length == 0) {
        alert('L’onglet «  Bâtiment »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }
    if((fd.field('Surface').value().length == 0) || (fd.field('Origine_affaire').value().length == 0)) {
        // activating a second tab:

        alert('L’onglet «  Projet »  contains empty inputs!!');

        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Comment: thanks , i tried your code , now it doesn't show me the alert anymore ,is it normal ? you can see the update of my code above

Comment: look at the first condition. You used the "!" AND the " == 0". You should use either 
`if (!fd.field('FileLeafRef').value().length)`
OR
`if (fd.field('FileLeafRef').value().length == 0)`. 
Not both at the same time ;)

This probably leads to a javascript error, so you can see it in browser's console (press F12).

Comment: hmm. about your function, when it returns "true", what does it do after? Depending on the utility of the value return, maybe you should just remove every "return false" in your function.

Comment: when It return true normaly, the forms is submitted and saved

Answer (score 0):

Add `.length` to every `.value()` :

```
if( (!fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value().length) ||
          (!fd.field('Secteur_activite').value().length) || 
                     (!fd.field('logo2').value().length) ||
            (!fd.field('Type_Effectifs').value().length))
{
    ...
}
```

**NOTE :** `.value().length` will return 0 if the value is empty what mean *false* in condition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks , i tried your code , now it doesn't show me the alert anymore ,is it normal ? you can see the update of my code above

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
if( (!fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value()) || (!fd.field('Secteur_activite').value()) || (!fd.field('logo2').value()) || (!fd.field('Type_Effectifs').value())){
```

to this:

```
if( (!fd.field('Typologie_x002d_client').value()) && (!fd.field('Secteur_activite').value()) && (!fd.field('logo2').value()) && (!fd.field('Type_Effectifs').value())){
```

as this alert will trigger every time when you have an empty field.

Comment: _as this alert will trigger every time when you have an empty field._.. No That will return the alert just when all the inputs are empty...